# error MSB4095: How to properly add additional settings in Visual Studio project properties dialog?

Tags: xaml, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to add additional config items to a project, with the aim to create an user-friendly Dlib project to compile and link Dlib.

This is my `.xaml` file, based on stuff I found in the visual studio install directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProjectSchemaDefinitions xmlns="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Build.Framework.XamlTypes;assembly=Microsoft.Build.Framework">
  <Rule Name="DLibOptionsRule" PageTemplate="generic" DisplayName="DLib settings">
    <Rule.Categories>
      <Category Name="dlib" DisplayName="DLib" />
    </Rule.Categories>
    <Rule.DataSource>
      <DataSource Persistence="ProjectFile" ItemType="" />
    </Rule.DataSource>
    <BoolProperty Name="DlibCUDAEnabled" DisplayName="Use CUDA" Default="false" Category="dlib" IncludeInCommandLine="false"/>
    <StringProperty Name="DlibCUDAPath" DisplayName="CUDA path" Description="Path to the CUDA library" Category="dlib" IncludeInCommandLine="false">
      <StringProperty.ValueEditors>
        <ValueEditor EditorType="DefaultStringPropertyEditor" DisplayName="&lt;Edit...&gt;"/>
        <ValueEditor EditorType="DefaultFilePropertyEditor" DisplayName="&lt;Browse...&gt;"/>
      </StringProperty.ValueEditors>
    </StringProperty>
  </Rule>
</ProjectSchemaDefinitions>
```

I then include that in this `.targets` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PropertyPageSchema Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\DlibOptions.xaml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="DlibSetDefines" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Message Text="Setting DLIB_USE_CUDA=%(DlibCUDAEnabled)" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <ClCompile>
        <PreprocessorDefinitions>DLIB_USE_CUDA=%(DlibCUDAEnabled);%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      </ClCompile>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

And finally, I include the targets just above the ending section of a Visual Studio project:

```
  <Import Project="DLibOptions.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

I can see the config items in the project properties dialog:

[image]

However, when I try to build, I get this error:

```
error MSB4095: The item metadata %(DlibCUDAEnabled) is being referenced without an item name.  Specify the item name by using %(itemname.DlibCUDAEnabled).
```

The full project can be found here if you'd be willing to take a look: https://github.com/Darker/dlib-vs-solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is

```
<Message Text="Setting DLIB_USE_CUDA=%(DlibCUDAEnabled)" />
```

can never work because it doesn't specify which Item to show so the Message task doesn't know what to loop over. You probably intended:

```
<Message Text="Setting DLIB_USE_CUDA=%(ClCompile.DlibCUDAEnabled)" />
```

but that's not super useful as it will just list the flag. This is more interesting and shows flag + srource file:

```
<Message Text="Setting DLIB_USE_CUDA=%(ClCompile.DlibCUDAEnabled) for %(ClCompile.Identity)" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I still don't quite understand what is going on. The error is gone after using your edit, but I am not sure if this is what I want. Why does the setting appear under ClCompile, and not as a global variable like `$(Platform)`?

Comment: Because each source file can be compiled with its own compiler settings (even though usually they are all the same), whereas platform is global for the entire build. You can check this in VS: right-click a source file, and there you can alter settings per file.

Comment: I have checked it, and the custom setting is not present in the source file properties. I have also found that `%(ClCompile.DlibCUDAEnabled)` evaluates to `""` (an empty string) regardless of what is set. I enabled maximum MSBuild verbosity and can see `1>DlibCUDAEnabled = true` along with other global properties as well as environment variables listed.

Comment: Yet, I also do get an error: ` error MSB4096: The item "..\dlib\dlib\all\source.cpp" in item list "ClCompile" does not define a value for metadata "DlibCUDAEnabled".  In order to use this metadata, either qualify it by specifying %(ClCompile.DlibCUDAEnabled), or ensure that all items in this list define a value for this metadata.` I will probably try to ask another question.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica I'm sorry I probably misunderstood what you wanted to do ; because I saw you using `%` I assumed you wanted to apply things per file. But now I realize perhaps you just used `%` because you saw `%(PreprocessorDefinitions)`; I read your question again and I have the impression the answer is simply that you have to use `$(DlibCUDAEnabled)` everywhere instead of `%(DlibCUDAEnabled)` i.e. just one single global property?